# como puedo consultar todos los datos de dos tablas en una sola consulta y sumarlos

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Estoy tratando de sumar los valores de estas tablas en una sola consulta, el hecho es que ya se suman, sin embargo, quiero que solo se sumen los que estén este las fechas que le indico, y como esta actualmente me suma todo sin importar el `BETWEEN`, inclusive hace caso miso al `WHERE` en el cual le especifico el username **spent**

```
router.get('/analitycs', isLoggedIn, async(req, res, next) => {
  const username = "spent"
  const date = `2022-09-01`;
  const date2 = `2022-09-31`;
  const sentencia_union = `
  SELECT sum(Amount) AS total 
     FROM debts_credit_card 
     WHERE username = ? BETWEEN ? AND ? 
  UNION
  SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TOTAL 
     FROM debts_loan WHERE username = ? BETWEEN ? AND ? 
`;
const queryPrincipal = `
     SELECT sum(total) as gran_total 
     FROM (${sentencia_union}) as total_debs`; // importante! ponerle nombre

const debts1 = await pool.query( queryPrincipal , [
   username,date,date2,username,date,date2
    ]
);

console.log(debts1)
  res.render('analitycs/analitycs')
});
```

Agradecería sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa una query que envuelva tu sentencia actual, la que pasaría a ser una subconsulta.

Refactorizando tu código actual, hoy tienes:

```
     const sentencia_union = `
           SELECT sum(Amount) AS total 
              FROM debts_credit_card 
              WHERE username = ? BETWEEN ? AND ? 
           UNION
           SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TOTAL 
              FROM debts_loan WHERE username = ? BETWEEN ? AND ? 
         `;

     const debts1 = await pool.query( sentencia_union , [
            username,date,date2,username,date,date2
             ]
      );
```

Y quedaría, en cambio:

```
     const sentencia_union = `
           SELECT sum(Amount) AS total 
              FROM debts_credit_card 
              WHERE username = ? BETWEEN ? AND ? 
           UNION
           SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TOTAL 
              FROM debts_loan WHERE username = ? BETWEEN ? AND ? 
         `;
     const queryPrincipal = `
              SELECT sum(total) as gran_total 
              FROM (${sentencia_union}) as subquery`; // importante! ponerle nombre

     const debts1 = await pool.query( queryPrincipal , [
            username,date,date2,username,date,date2
             ]
      );
```

Sólo procura ponerle un alias porque sino MySQL devolverá el error: "`every derived table must have its alias`" o algo así.

(Parto de la base que no vas a traer más columnas, así que no me preucuparé de la cláusula   GROUP BY )

---

#### Edit muy importante!!

En mi respuesta sólo advertí uno de los dos problemas (aquel donde obtienes dos registros cuando en realidad necesitas uno) pero no caí en la cuenta de que la sentencia SQL no hace lo que describes. Tú intentas obtener los registros asociados a *cierto username* **Y** que hayan ocurrido *en un cierto intervalo de fechas*.

Esto debiera consultarse con

```
   SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TOTAL 
          FROM debts_loan 
       WHERE username = ? AND creation_date BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

(me inventé el nombre del campo fecha)

Lo que tienes ahora, específicamente

```
  WHERE username = 'spent' BETWEEN `2022-09-01` AND `2022-09-31`;
```

en ninguna parte considera la fecha, y debido a la naturaleza del operador  `BETWEEN`, en mysql, el error pasa desapercbido debido a [la conversión implícita de tipos](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between). Básicamente, si todo se coerciona a booleanos, podrías consultar

```
  WHERE username BETWEEN true and true
```

Lo cual trae por definición la tabla completa.

**Comentario o recomendación**

*Te sugiero que no edites la pregunta como respuesta a potenciales respuestas, visto que con ello se vuelve inconsistente, y pareciera que te respondo con el mismo código de tu pregunta.*

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias @ffflabs por tu respuesta, cambiaste mi perspectiva de organización del código, el hecho es que en lo absoluto funciono, me sigue sumando todos los datos de las tablas a las cuales se le pidió sumar solo los dato de la columna `Amount` que estén entre las fechas, algo para agregar es en el caso de que quiera agregar otras tablas como seria de igual manera.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha sido de gran utilidad sin embargo, en el caso de que quiera agregar a la suma otras tablas digamos que 3 mas ?.

Comment: estás en el plan gratuito y por ahora eso sólo cubre preguntas de hasta 3 tablas. Para preguntas de 5 tablas debes contratar el plan DEVELOPER.

Nah, simplemente sigues apilando UNION con el respectivo nombre de la tabla y campos que correspondan. La prumera tabla le da nombre al campo así que en la cláusula SELECT da igual como se llame

Comment: muchas gracias de verdad